# UIColor colorWithString giving me an error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is from an older project that I am trying to update.  I get errors on every line that uses UIColor colorWithString.  I'm sort of a novice so even though I've looked up CIColor and colorWithHex I can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas?

```
`UILabel *versionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 40, 320, 20)];
versionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
versionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
versionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
versionLabel.text = NSStringf(@"v%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]);
versionLabel.font = [self customFontWithSize:10];
versionLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithString:@"9fb4cs"];`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
colorWithString
```

isn't a standard method of [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html)

It looks like you were using a *UIColor category* to extend the built in functionality, possibly [ColorUtils](https://github.com/nicklockwood/ColorUtils)

Is this still referenced by the project and is it included in your source file?

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://github.com/nicklockwood/ColorUtils) of the non-standard category `ColorUtils` you are using.

> Hexadecimal strings can be prefixed with #, 0x or nothing and can have 3, 6 or 8 digits. 6 digits is the standard rrggbb format, 8 is the same but with an alpha component, 3 is a shorthand used commonly in CSS, where each hex digit is repeated, so #29f becomes #2299ff, for example.

So change your last line to

```
versionLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithString:@"#9fb4cs"];
```

Comment: I tried that and still gave me an error so decided to use colorwithRGB

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was an old component and I switched to colorwithRGBA and used this converter to give me the rgb values http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm